# What was Jesus actually promising in John 6:35 and when is this promise fulfilled?

Tags: john, jesus, chronology, soteriology, figure-of-speech

John 6:35:

> 35 And Jesus said to them, `I am the bread of the life; **he who is coming unto me may not hunger, and he who is believing in me may not thirst -- at any time**; [YLT]
>
> 35 And Jesus said unto them, I am the bread of life: **he that cometh to me shall never hunger; and he that believeth on me shall never thirst**. [KJV]
>
> Jesus said to them, “I am the bread of life; **whoever comes to me shall not hunger, and whoever believes in me shall never thirst**. [ESV]

- What does it mean to "never hunger"? What does it mean to "never thirst"?
- How can someone meet the promise's condition ("whoever comes to me ...") ? How can someone come to Jesus?
- When does someone experience the promised effects ("shall never hunger, shall never thirst") ? In this life? In the afterlife?
- Does it follow from this passage that, once someone comes to Jesus, their salvation is assured (since they are promised to never hunger and thirst again)?

Comment: The entire tenor of this question appears to be about Calvinism vs Arminianism - a large subject.

Comment: I have made an attempt to answer some of the questions below but this subject is so large - God is the initiator of salvation - we only come to God by His invitation which is issued to all people.  Perhaps this questions could be split is several parts.

Comment: These questions need to be taken one at a time. In comment, it appears you are actually researching the 'once saved, always saved' theology so this might better be asked on SE-Christianity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What was Jesus actually promising in John 6:35 and when is this promise fulfilled?**
John 6:35

> 35 And Jesus said unto them, I am the bread of life: he that cometh to
> me shall never hunger; and he that believeth on me shall never thirst.
> [KJV]

**What does it mean to "never hunger"? What does it mean to "never thirst"?**

In context, Jesus' words are directed to the spiritual sons of God, the partakers of the heavenly calling [Hebrews 3:1 NASB] and in Vs 40, Jesus says He will resurrect them on the last day. They will be resurrected to be with him in his heavenly kingdom. [Luke 12:32]

**How can someone meet the promise's condition ("whoever comes to me ...") ? How can someone come to Jesus?**

John 6:40  Amplified Bible

> For this is My Father’s will and purpose, that everyone who sees the
> Son and believes in Him [as Savior] will have eternal life, and I will
> raise him up [from the dead] on the last day.”

**When does someone experience the promised effects ("shall never hunger, shall never thirst") ? In this life? In the afterlife?**

When resurrected as spiritual beings on the last day,

Luke 12:32

> 32 Do not be afraid, little flock, because your Father has chosen to
> give you the kingdom

**Does it follow from this passage that, once someone comes to Jesus, their salvation is assured** (since they are promised to never hunger and thirst again)?

Lot's wife had her salvation assured, she started on the way on the road out of Sodom and Gomorrah followed by the Angels, yet she looked back and died.  Likewise, Paul urges his fellow Christians not to ruin their opportunity for salvation but exercise self-control, and run the full race in strict discipline to the end.

1 Corinthians 9:24-27 NASB

> 24 Do you not know that those who run in a race all run, but only one
> receives the prize? Run in such a way that you may win. 25 Everyone
> who competes in the games exercises self-control in all things. So
> they do it to obtain a perishable wreath, but we an imperishable. 26
> Therefore I run in such a way as not to run aimlessly; I box in such a
> way, as [a]to avoid hitting air; 27 but I strictly discipline my body
> and make it my slave, so that, after I have preached to others, I
> myself will not be disqualified.

Answer (score 1):

Upon genuinely encountering Christ and His teachings, one's soul is completely fulfilled or satiated, and thus will never crave anything else from anyone else ever again, in terms of either morality or spirituality, as his own disciples later confirm, within the very same chapter:

> <sup>John 6:66-69</sup> From this time many of his disciples turned back and no longer followed him. “You do not want to leave too, do you?” Jesus asked the Twelve. Simon Peter answered him:
>
> > “Lord, **to whom shall we go? You have the words of eternal life.** We have come to believe and to know that you are the Holy One of God.”

Comment: So "once saved, always saved" is true?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: I am not a Calvinist, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Not being able to lose salvation is taught by many non-Calvinists too. But theology questions belong on [christianity.se].

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is based on Matt 5:6 -

> Blessed are those who hunger and thirst for righteousness, for they
> will be filled.

That is, Jesus used the metaphor of hunger and thirsting as a parallel for those who have the following characteristics, using the extended metaphor:

- Jesus is the bread of life (John 6:33, 35, 48, 51) signifying that God appreciates those who want eternal life through Jesus Christ.  See especially John 5:11, 12, " ... he who has the Son has life; he who does not have the Son does not have life."
- Jesus is also the source of the water of life, John 4:14, Rev 22:1, 17, etc.

That is, people must "want" Jesus as the source of life as much as physical food.  This is part of what is known in the technical theological jargon as the doctrine of the "Imitation of Christ" - see appendix 1 below.

John summarized the culmination of this process of "eating the flesh of Jesus and drinking His blood" in 1 John 3 -

> **1** Behold what manner of love the Father has given to us, that we should be called children of God. And that is what we are! The reason
> the world does not know us is that it did not know Him. **2** Beloved,
> we are now children of God, and what we will be has not yet been
> revealed. We know that when Christ appears, **we will be like Him**,
> for we will see Him as He is. **3** And everyone who has this hope in
> Him purifies himself, just as Christ is pure.

Since Jesus is the "bread of life" and the "water of life" (there is an allusion to the tree of life and the river of the water of life in Eden and the New Jerusalem, Rev 21, 22), this is a source that is inexhaustible and thus, when we eat and drink from such an unlimited source, we will never be spiritually hungry or thirsty again.

As to whether John 6:35 can be used to support the idea of "once save always saved" - the simple answer is no for two reasons -

- The text is not discussing being saved but the idea of spritual growth and nourishment as already shown - Christ is the inexhaustible supply.
- The Bible does not teach this - see appendix 2 below.

**APPENDIX 1 - Imitation of Christ**

The Imitation of Christ is one of the central parts of the plan of salvation.  Essentially, the Bible tells converted Christians that they must behave in the same way as Jesus did.  Indeed, Jesus’ final instruction to His disciples was to make more disciples (Matt 28:19) – disciples were imitators of their masters and thus became like their teachers (Luke 6:40).

Here is a sample of the huge amount of material available on this subject.

- Made like God.  Gen 1:26, 27, 5:1, 9:6, Eph 4:20-24, 1 John 3:2.  Note that this means that one of the purposes of salvation is to restore the likeness of God in humans that sin has erased.
- Walk as Jesus walked.  1 John 2:6.
- Jesus was led by the Spirit Matt 4:1.  The Christian must be born of the Spirit (John 3:5) by receiving the gift of the Spirit (Acts 2:38) and walk by the Spirit (Gal 5:25, John 6:63, Phil 3:3, John 4:24).  In fact, the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).
- Love as Jesus loved.  John 13:34, 35, 15:12, 1 John 4:8, 11, 19, Eph 5:1, 2.
- Lay down life for friends.  John 15:13, Eph 5:2.
- Jesus’ suffering leaves us an example.  John 16:33, 1 Cor 7:28, 2 Tim 1:4, Heb 13:12, 13, 1 Peter 2:21.
- Because Jesus was persecuted, so are His followers.  John 15:20, 21.
- Conformed to the likeness of the Son.  Rom 8:29.
- Transforming our will and bodies to conform to God’s will.  Rom 12:1, 2.
- Jesus was baptised (Matt 3:13-17, Mark 1:9-11, Luke 3:21, 22) and so should we be baptised, Matt 28:19, Acts 2:38, 10:48, 16:31, 22:16, Rom 6:1-9, etc.  See “Baptism”.
- Forgive as Jesus forgave.  Matt 6:12, 14, 15, 18:35, Eph 4:32, Col 3:13.
- Be imitators of God.  Eph 5:1.
- Be holy as Jesus is holy.  Lev 11:44, 45, 1 Peter 1:15, 16.
- Be pure as He is pure.  1 John 3:3.
- Partakers of the divine nature.  2 Peter 1:4.
- We are being changed into Christ’s glory (= reputation).  2 Cor 3:18.
- Pray as Jesus prayed.  Luke 11:1.
- We are to have the mind of Christ.  Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16.
- Be kind because God is kind.  Luke 6:34, 35.
- Be merciful because God is merciful.  Luke 6:36.
- Be servants to others as Jesus was.  John 13:15-17, 1 Peter 4:11b, Matt 20:24-28.
- Be patient as Jesus was patient.  1 Tim 1:16.
- Talk/speak as Jesus speaks.  1 Peter 4:11a.
- Be “perfect” (= mature and generous to enemies) as the Father is.  Matt 5:48.
- Husbands should love their wives as Christ loved His people and gave Himself for her.  Eph 5:25.
- Keep the commandments as Jesus kept the commandments.  John 14:15, 15:10.
- Abide in Christ as Christ abides in us.  John 15:4.
- Jesus is the “beginning and the end” (Rev 22:13) and Jesus is the beginning and end of our faith (Heb 12:2).
- We are co-heirs with Christ of glory.  Rom 8:17.
- Jesus gave his all and we must give up all things for Him.  Rom 8:32.
- Jesus is called the “Lamb of God” (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19) and so are His followers (John 10:1-18, 21:15-17)
- Jesus washed the disciples’ feet (John 13:1-17) and so should we (John 13:14-17)
- Jesus is the light of the world (John 1:4, 9, 8:12, 9:5) and so are we (Matt 5:14-16)
- Jesus is the “firstborn” Luke 2:7, Rom 8:29, Col 1:15, 18, Heb 1:6, Rev 1:5, and we are to compose the church/assembly of the firstborn, Heb 12:23; see also Rom 8:23 & Rev 14:4 where we are also called first-fruits to God and the Lamb.
- Jesus is our sacrifice of atonement and likened to a sacrificial lamb offered for us John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, Eph 5:2, 1 John 2:2, 4:10, Heb 10:10, 12, Rom 3:25, 1 Peter 1:19, etc.  Similarly, the life of a Christian is lived sacrificially for Christ Rom 12:1, Phil 2:17, Heb 13:15.

The Bible strongly emphasises the imitation of Christ by the mechanism of beholding Christ (Phil 2:4, 5, Heb 12:2, 3, 1 Cor 2:16, Col 3:1-4, 2 Cor 3:18, Rom 13:14, John 17:17, Matt 6:19-33, 12:33-35, Rom 8:12-14; contrast 2 Kings 17:15, Ps 115:4-8, 135:15-18, Prov 10:24, 24:8, 9).

> “Salvation is found in no one else, for there is no other name under
> heaven given among mankind by which we must be saved.” (Acts 4:12)

In fact, it is the imitation of Christ that gives Christians the title; “Christian” meaning, one who is like Christ.

**APPENDIX 2 - Can salvation in Christ be lost?**

The simple answer is "YES" and there are many examples of this.  Here is a sample.

- Eze 18:21-28 also teaches that the wicked can reform and be saved, and the righteous can apostatise and be lost.  Both situations are incompatible with Calvinism’s view of salvation and humanity.
- Rom 11:17-21 discusses the warning that people who had been grafted into the “olive tree” of the Christian community could be broken off if they were unfaithful.
- 1 Cor 9:27 Paul says he disciplines his body to keep it under control so that after preaching to others he does not become a castaway/disqualified.  That is, Paul believed that it was possible that he could lose his way and become lost.
- 1 Cor 10:12 also contains a stern warning from Paul, “If you think you are standing firm, be careful that you don’t fall.”
- Galatians 5:4: "You have been severed from Christ, you who are seeking to be justified by law; you have fallen from grace"
- Gal 6:9 says, “Let us not become weary in doing good, for at the proper time we will reap a harvest if we do not give up.”
- 1 Tim 6:10, For the love of money is the root of all kinds of evils.  It is through this craving that some have wandered away from the faith and pierced themselves with many pangs.
- Heb 2:1-3, We must pay closer attention, therefore, to what we have heard, so that we do not drift away.  For if the message spoken by angels was binding, and every transgression and disobedience received its just punishment, how shall we escape if we neglect such a great salvation?
- Similarly, Heb 6:4-6 also teaches that some “who have once been enlightened, who have tasted the heavenly gift, who have shared in the Holy Spirit…” can fall away.
- Heb 10:26: If we(!) deliberately keep on sinning after receiving the knowledge of the truth, no sacrifice for sins is left
- Heb 10:29: How much more severely do you think someone deserves to be punished who has trampled the Son of God underfoot, who has treated as an unholy thing the blood of the covenant that sanctified them and who has insulted the Spirit of grace.  This verse clearly shows that it is possible to be sanctified and subsequently lost.
- Heb 10:35: Therefore, do not throw away your confidence which has a great reward.
- Heb 10:36: You need to persevere so that when you have done the will of God you will receive what he has promised.
- Heb 13:9, “Do not be led away by diverse and strange teachings, for it is good for the heart to be strengthened by grace …”
- 2 Peter 1:10, “make your calling and election sure”.  This clearly allows for the possibility of losing one’s election.
- 2 Peter 2:21, “It would have been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than to have known it and then to turn their backs on the sacred command that was passed on to them.”
- 2 Peter 3:17 contains a very stern and sobering warning to be on guard that we do not fall from our secure position.  Verse 14 contains a similar warning.
- Jesus’ parable of the 10 virgins contains two classes of people called “wise” and “foolish”.  All were invited to the wedding; All were virgins symbolising purity, see Rev 14:5; All had lamps, ie, lights symbolising Christ as the light of the world, John 1:4, 9, 8:12, 9:5, Matt 5:14-16; All, at least initially had oil - but this is the crux of the parable - five virgins had enough oil and five did not have enough because they complained that their lamps were going out.  In the NT oil represents the gift of the Holy Spirit (Luke 4:18, Acts 10:38, 2 Cor 1:21, 22, 1 John 2:20).  Thus, Jesus teaches that some who are called and have been given the Holy Spirit (see also Heb 6:4-6) can still be excluded from the Kingdom of God.
- Jesus’ parable of the vine (John 15:1-8) says two interesting things: (a) that branches (connected to the vine of Jesus) that do not bear fruit are cut off (v2); and (b) the bearing of fruit is to prove that we are Jesus’ disciples.
- Jesus’ parable of the sower, or perhaps the parable of the soils (Matt 13:1-23, Mark 4:1-20, Luke 8:4-15) contains several classes of people (soils) who start out well in the Christian life but lose their way.  The conclusion is also significant: “by their constancy bear fruit”. (Luke 8:15)
- Jesus’ parable of the banquet (Luke 14:16-24) contains a very good example of people rejecting the call (or “election”) of God as well as God having to ask some people more than once and begging them to the wedding banquet.  Jesus’ conclusion is, again, significant, “not one of those men who have been invited shall taste of my banquet.”  In the parallel passage of Matt 22:1-14, Jesus concludes by saying, “*For many are called, but few are chosen.*”

Comment: Someone recently brought up John 6:35 to defend "once saved, always saved" doctrine, meaning that once a person, in this life, accepts Jesus as their Lord and Savior and becomes born-again, the promise in John 6:35 is immediately fulfilled, which means that they will never thirst and hunger again, and if this is true, then it is impossible for such a person to lose their salvation. That's why in the OP I asked several questions, including point 4. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator - I will add something to the answer to show what the Scripture says.

Answer (score 0):

> They said to him, “Sir, give us this bread always.”
> Jesus said to them, “I am the bread of life; whoever comes to me shall not hunger, and whoever believes in me shall never thirst.
> (John 6:34-35, ESV)

> εἶπον οὖν πρὸς αὐτόν· κύριε, πάντοτε δὸς ἡμῖν τὸν ἄρτον τοῦτον.
>  εἶπεν αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς· ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ ἄρτος τῆς ζωῆς· ὁ ἐρχόμενος πρὸς ⸀ἐμὲ οὐ μὴ πεινάσῃ, καὶ ὁ πιστεύων εἰς ἐμὲ οὐ μὴ ⸁διψήσει πώποτε.
> (John 6:34-35, NA28)

**"What does it mean to "never hunger"? What does it mean to "never thirst"?"**

In 6:34 people asked for bread to mean their physical hunger.  Jesus described spiritual hunger and thirst.  D.A. Carson explained what "never hunger" and "never thirst" means.

> When they said ‘from now on give us this bread’ (v. 34), they were suggesting that the bread of heaven needed to be given again and again. But Jesus insists, He who comes to me will never go hungry. The thought is not unlike 13:9–10: the person who has been washed by Jesus does not need another bath, but only ‘to wash his feet’. So the hungry and thirsty person who comes to Jesus finds his hunger satisfied and his thirst quenched. This does not mean there is no need for continued dependence upon him, for continued feeding upon him; it does mean there is no longer that core emptiness that the initial encounter with Jesus has met. The consummating satiation occurs when those ‘who have washed their robes … in the blood of the Lamb’ stand ‘before the throne of God’ and experience the oracle: ‘Never again will they hunger; never again will they thirst’ (Rev. 7:14–16).
> --
> Carson, D. A. (1991). The Gospel according to John (p. 288). Inter-Varsity Press; W.B. Eerdmans.

**"How can someone meet the promise's condition ("whoever comes to me ...") ? How can someone come to Jesus?"**

In Jesus' statement is a synonymous parallel, "whoever comes to me shall not hunger, and whoever believes in me shall never thirst" Thus, "whoever comes to me" = "whoever believes in me."

Jesus had previously said:

> Then they said to him, “What must we do, to be doing the works of God?” 29 Jesus answered them, “This is the work of God, that you believe in him whom he has sent.”
> (John 6:28–29, ESV)

In the Gospel of John note:

> But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God, 13 who were born, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God.
> (John 1:12–13, ESV)

> And as Moses lifted up the serpent in the wilderness, so must the Son of Man be lifted up, 15 that whoever believes in him may have eternal life.
> 16 “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life. 17 For God did not send his Son into the world to condemn the world, but in order that the world might be saved through him. 18 Whoever believes in him is not condemned, but whoever does not believe is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only Son of God.
> (John 3:14–18, ESV)

> Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him.
> (John 3:36, ESV)

> Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into judgment, but has passed from death to life.
> (John 5:24, ESV)

> For this is the will of my Father, that everyone who looks on the Son and believes in him should have eternal life, and I will raise him up on the last day.”
> (John 6:40, ESV)

> Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever believes has eternal life.
> (John 6:47, ESV)

> On the last day of the feast, the great day, Jesus stood up and cried out, “If anyone thirsts, let him come to me and drink. 38 Whoever believes in me, as the Scripture has said, ‘Out of his heart will flow rivers of living water.’ ” 39 Now this he said about the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the Spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet glorified.
> (Jn 7:37–39, ESV)

> Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in me, though he die, yet shall he live, 26 and everyone who lives and believes in me shall never die. Do you believe this?”
> (John 11:25–26, ESV)

> “Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever believes in me will also do the works that I do; and greater works than these will he do, because I am going to the Father.
> (John 14:12, ESV)

> but these are written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name.
> (John 20:31, ESV)

**"When does someone experience the promised effects ("shall never hunger, shall never thirst") ? In this life? In the afterlife?"**

In the Gospel of John Jesus spoke of eternal life as present tense.  See John 3:36; 5:24,26; 6:24,47,54.  Thus, it applies to now and continues in the afterlife.

**"Does it follow from this passage that, once someone comes to Jesus, their salvation is assured (since they are promised to never hunger and thirst again)?"**

It's a stretch to interpret "never hunger and thirst again" in this way.  Better verses are:

> All that the Father gives me will come to me, and whoever comes to me I will never cast out.
> (John 6:37, ESV)

> My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me. 28 I give them eternal life, and they will never perish, and no one will snatch them out of my hand. 29 My Father, who has given them to me, is greater than all, and no one is able to snatch them out of the Father’s hand.
> (John 10:27–29, ESV)

Comment: I feel like accepting this answer. However, the stone in the shoe that is stopping me is your answer to the 4th question, which seems at odds with Dottard and OzzieOzzie's views. Do you believe salvation can be lost?

Comment: @Spirit Realm Investigator - only in the sense that a lost person can think they are saved and fall away.  Thus, not from God's viewpoint, but from the human viewpoint.  For example, from the human experiential viewpoint, the Sun goes around the Earth, but actually the Earth rotates.